Bounded in probability and continuous function
Suppose $ X_1, X_2, … $ is a sequence of random vectors in $ \mathbb{R}^d $ that is bounded in probability. That is, for every $ \epsilon > 0$, there exists $M_\epsilon > 0$ such that:
$ \mathbb{P} [\|X_n\|> M_\epsilon]<\epsilon$
for every $n$.
Take $g$ a continuous function from $ \mathbb{R}^d $ to $ \mathbb{R}^k $. Prove that the sequence $g(X_1),…,g(X_n)$ is also bounded in probability. I’m having some trouble with it, though I thought it should be very straightforward.

You can argue that for every $m>0$ there is a $c_m>0$ such that $||x||\leq m \implies |g(x)|\leq c_m$.

I see how this solves the question, thank you. Still, I can intuitively believe this to be true for a continuous function but would appreciate some help with how to do it more formally.

Oh, it’s compact. Everything is solved, thank you!

FYI - \|X_n\| provides a nicer norm symbol than ||X_n||: $|X_n|$ vs $||X_n||$.

That’s nice, thanks.
